# Getting the last value of a key value pair in a json like string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a json like string (incomplete json) in which I am trying to retrieve the value of the last key:value pair. The incomplete json like string looks like this:

```
"BaseCode":null,"BrokerSymbol":null,"CustID":null,"SynthDesc":""}],"@nexturl":"https://someurl.com"}
```

I am trying to access the value of the `@nexturl` key and this is the code I've till now:

```
str1.split(":")[-1]
```

this gives the output `//someurl.com`. 2 issues here are that splitting on `:` removes the `https` prefix and also doesn't seem like a great approach as if the url contains any more `:` it will split on that. Is there someway I can get the entire value of `@nexturl` key?

Comment: yes, but why are you spliting as a json string? that's generally a bad idea. I think it's better to parse the json and get the last key-value pair.

Comment: Why not `json.loads('{"foo": [{' + str1)["@nexturl"]`

Comment: `str1.split(":", 1)[-1]` will only split on the first occurence of the ":" symbol

Comment: @rv.kvetch it's not a complete json string. I do not want to rectify the string to be a legit json string and then do a json.loads.

Comment: Question: Can you guarantee that your last key:value par will be @nexturl ?

Comment: @LeshawnRice that just gives me the entire string back as the first occurence of `:` is in the first key:value pair.

Comment: @Bruno yes sir, that'll be the same key.

Comment: Then you always know your key, you just need to grab the value isn't?
mystr = str(mystr.split('"@nexturl":')[-1]).rstrip("}")

Comment: One addition, in case you wanna return both in the same string maybe this is more 'efficient': mystr[mystr.index('"@nexturl":'):len(mystr)-1] (It removes the last }') and creates a substring starting in the '@nexturl'

Comment: @Bruno Can you put your second comment as an answer and I can close this. The second one is much better as I can use the `nexturl` as a variable if I need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested, assuming your string is as follows:

```
mystr = '"BaseCode":null,"BrokerSymbol":null,"CustID":null,"SynthDesc":""}],"@nexturl":"https://someurl.com"}'
```

You can grab the key:value pair containing “@nexturl” by using:

```
mystr[mystr.index('"@nexturl":'):len(mystr)-1]
```